# How to interpret the output of LDA (discriminant analysis) in R

Tags: linear, discriminant-analysis

I'm doing a study where I have 4 groups of people who take 5 different psychological tests. I'm interested in determining what test (or tests) is better at determining in which group a person is in. To do this, I have read I can use LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis).

I have used the following code:

```
my_lda = lda(participant_group ~ test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5, my_data)
```

The output I get has different sections, some of them I don't quite understand:

- First, I get the **prior probabilities of groups** (i.e., how likely it is for the participants to end up in one or another group based on the data I collected) - I think I understand this part.

```
Prior probabilities of groups:
  group_1   group_2   group_3   group_4 
0.1935484 0.2983871 0.3387097 0.1693548
```

- Then, I get the **group means**, which I assume are the means my participants got in the tests (organized by group).

```
Group means:
             test1          test2           test3             test4            test5
group_1 74.06042         23.12500        17.08333          36.58333         13.50000
group_2 50.67886         22.21622        19.45946          31.62162         18.86486
group_3 69.71243         22.85714        18.47619          35.38095         14.64286
group_4 37.15314         22.19048        19.90476          28.71429         21.28571
```

- Thirdly, I get the **coefficients**, which is the part I'm struggling with. From what I've read, this is supposed to tell me which test has more weight (aka. is more important) when it comes to dividing people into groups. So, for LD1, for example, both test4 and test5 have more weight (compared to the others). However, they have a negative weight. *How can I interpret the negative sign? And, does this mean these two tests are good at predicting groups (they also have a high weight in LD2)?*

```
Coefficients of linear discriminants:
                          LD1           LD2         LD3
test1               -0.02042613 -0.0008603193 -0.03856752
test2                0.35315854 -0.0105201433  0.19364442
test3               -0.19335860 -0.0128410283 -0.30453445
test4               -0.42951316 -0.7805021655  0.42228513
test5               -0.48963686 -0.7305423473  0.36484221
```

- Lastly, I get the **proportion of trace**. I think this is telling me what percentage of the data can be explained by each of these three LD functions. For example, LD1 explains roughly 60% of the data, which means that it is the most informative function of the three, and thus, whichever tests have more weight for LD1 will also be the best at predicting groups. *Is this interpretation correct?*

```
Proportion of trace:
   LD1    LD2    LD3 
0.6044 0.2204 0.1752
```

I'm also not sure how I should report my results in a paper. *Should I include all the output or just the coefficients and proportion of trace for LD1, since it's the most informative?*

Comment: What you need to report depends on your domain and the context, but you can get a good explanation of how to interpret the output here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087417/lda-interpretation